# ghcup install: Permission denied when writing to ~/.ghcup/cache directory

Tags: haskell, curl, permissions, ghcup

I'm attempting to install ghcup on Ubuntu with:

`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh`

using the default options (prepend to .bashrc, don't install HLS, dont install Stack).

The problem is that I'm receiving a `permission denied` error when the script attempts to write the `ghcup-0.0.6.yaml.tmp` file to the `~/.ghcup/cache` directory and I'm not sure why.

Permissions on the directory are 1775 (drwxrwxr-x). Upgrading them to 1777 (drwxrwxrwt) and re-running the curl command produces the same error. The directory owner is me (not root), and I'm running the curl command without `sudo` as directed by the ghcup installation instructions.

Full command output:

```
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 24.3M  100 24.3M    0     0  5782k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 5783k
[ Info  ] downloading: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/haskell/ghcup-metadata/master/ghcup-0.0.6.yaml as file /home/austin/.ghcup/cache/ghcup-0.0.6.yaml
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file 
Warning: /home/austin/.ghcup/cache/ghcup-0.0.6.yaml.tmp: Permission denied
  0  134k    0   858    0     0   8429      0  0:00:16 --:--:--  0:00:16  8495
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
[ Warn  ] Could not get download info, trying cached version (this may not be recent!)
[ ...   ] If this problem persists, consider switching downloader via: 
[ ...   ]     ghcup config set downloader Wget
[ Error ] JSON decoding failed with: YAML exception:
[ ...   ] Yaml file not found: /home/austin/.ghcup/cache/ghcup-0.0.6.yaml
[ ...   ] Consider removing /home/austin/.ghcup/cache/ghcup-0.0.6.yaml manually.
[ ...   ] 
"_eghcup upgrade" failed!
```

Would love an explanation as to what's happening and how to resolve it so I can start learning Haskell! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Solved:

Turns out the `snap` version of curl is semi-broken. I got a successful `ghcup` install after running:

```
sudo snap remove curl

sudo apt install curl
```